# Appending to the top of a nested JSON dict

Tags: python

Consider the following json dict:

```
print(new_table)

{
    "Name": "areas_json",
    "Parameters": {
        "CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion": "1.0",
        "CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion": "1.0",
        "UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER": "crawler",
        "averageRecordSize": "100",
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add (append) another line to `Parameters` at the top.

I've attempted this with the following code:

```
new_table["Parameters"].append({"new_row":"example"})
```

I get the error:  `'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`

What is the right way to append to a python dictionary?

Desired output:

```
print(new_table)

{
    "Name": "areas_json",
    "Parameters": {
        "new_row":"example",
        "CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion": "1.0",
        "CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion": "1.0",
        "UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER": "crawler",
        "averageRecordSize": "100",
    }
}
```

Comment: `new_table['Parameters']["new_row"]="example"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `update` instead of `append` as:

```
t['Parameters'].update({"new_row":'example'})
```

`append` is for the list object.

Comment: Yes, this works. It appends it to the bottom of "Parameters" though (see desired output). Do you know if it's possible to make it append to the top without making a rearranging loop?

Comment: `dict` has not ordering by default. use `ordereddict` if you need the keys to be ordered.

Comment: I see. Thank you for both answers.

Comment: Happy to help, please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as resolved.